# How to show JsDoc Quick Documentation for Javascript Constructors in Webstorm?

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea, constructor, webstorm, jsdoc

How can I lookup the function parameters of the constructor of this class with
Quick Documentation?

[image]

When doing that, it always shows me the module description instead of the constructor description. So I always have to jump to the class implementation, to check the parameters, which costs me a little bit of time and interrupting my workflow.

[image]

If you show the QuickDocumentation for any prototype function, everything works like expected.

[image]

How can I force WebStorm to show me the constructor description instead of the module description?